# How to use Fancy box with a Gravity Form and close on submit?

Tags: jquery, fancybox

I'm using a fancy box iFrame for a Gravity Form in WordPress. Is it possible after the form has been submitted rather than re-directing within the iFrame, close the fancy box and re-direct within the browser? And if the form has failed validation, stay open until the form has validated (via ajax)?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The problem is because it is in an iframe. Try creating your own modal (with the code that I placed below).

When that is compete do the following:

In the "Form Settings > Confirmation" tab in the admin. Click the radio button for "redirect" if the URL is outside of your site OR click the radio button for "page" and select an internal page that dwells inside of your site.

## The code below can be used for a single or multiple forms using the same modal wrapper.

**The Modal HTML/ PHP GFORM (shortcode):**

```
<div class="modal_wrapper ac">
<div class="modal_form">

    <div class="modal_contact">
        <h3 class="title al">Contact</h3>
        <p class="al mb20">Send us a message and we will respond as soon as possible.</p>
        <?php 
            echo do_shortcode('[gravityform id="1" title="false" description="false" ajax="true"]');
        ?>
    </div>

    <div class="modal_request">
        <h3 class="title al">Request</h3>
        <p class="al mb20">Make a request for custom personalized jewelry for someone special or for you.</p>
        <?php 
            echo do_shortcode('[gravityform id="2" title="false" description="false" ajax="true"]');
        ?>
    </div>

    <span class="close-btn"></span>
</div>
```

**The CSS:**

```
.al {
text-align:left;
}

.mb20 {
margin-bottom:20px;
}

.close-btn {
background:transparent url('../images/close_btn.png') no-repeat 0 0;
position:absolute;
width:26px;
height:26px;
top:-10px;
right:-10px;
cursor:pointer;
opacity:1.0;
-moz-opacity:1.0;
-webkit-opacity:1.0;
-o-opacity:1.0;
-khtml-opacity:1.0;
-ms-opacity:1.0;
outline:none;
text-indent:-9999px;
}

.close-btn:hover {
opacity:0.8;
-moz-opacity:0.8;
-webkit-opacity:0.8;
-o-opacity:0.8;
-khtml-opacity:0.8;
-ms-opacity:0.8;
}

.modal_wrapper {
background:transparent url('../images/bg_modal.png') !important;
position:fixed;
z-index:999;
left:0;
top:0;
filter:alpha(opacity=100) !important;
-moz-opacity:1.0 !important;
opacity:1.0 !important;
display:none;
}

.modal_form {
top:100px;
background:#fff;
position:relative;
border:3px solid #efddc1;
width:370px;
height:auto;
padding:10px 20px;
border-radius:3px; -moz-border-radius:3px; -webkit-border-radius:3px; -khtml-border-radius:3px; -ms-border-radius:3px; -o-border-radius:3px;
}

.modal_form .title {
font-size:26px;
color:#f76b4f;
margin:10px 0;
text-transform:uppercase;
}
```

**The Jquery:**

```
// Hides by default
$('.modal_wrapper').hide();

// Makes the wrapper the same Height & Width as the window
$('.modal_wrapper').css({
    'width': $(window).width() + 'px',
    'height': $(window).height() + 'px'
}); 

// Places the form grandparent in the center vertically & horizontally
$('.modal_form').css({
    'margin-left': '-' + ($('.modal_form').width()/2) + 'px',
    'left': '50%'
});

// Hides the forms parent
$('.modal_contact').hide();
$('.modal_request').hide();


// Makes sure that is stays vertically & horizontally centered when the window is resized
$(window).resize(function(){
    $('.modal_wrapper').css({
        'width': $(window).width() + 'px',
        'height': $(window).height() + 'px'
    });
    $('.modal_form').css({
        'margin-left': '-' + ($('.modal_form').width()/2) + 'px',
        'left': '50%'
    });
});


// Place this or these (contact_form, request_form) class on anything that you want to show the modal
// be sure to hide the other forms in the modal
$('.contact_form').click(function(){
    $('.modal_wrapper').fadeIn('fast');
    $('.modal_contact').show();
    $('.modal_request').hide();
});

$('.request_form').click(function(){
    $('.modal_wrapper').fadeIn('fast');
    $('.modal_contact').hide();
    $('.modal_request').show();
});

// Close the modal
$('.close-btn').click(function(){
    $(this).closest('.modal_wrapper').fadeOut('fast');
});
```